# Recursively constructing an object in OpenSCAD

Tags: recursion, openscad

So I'm trying to build a simple stack of scaled cubes using a recursive function:

```
function stack(levels) = (
  levels <= 0
  ? cube([1,1,1], center=true)
  : union() {
    cube([1,1,1], center=true);
    translate([0, 0, 0.9]) scale([1, 1, 0.9]) stack(levels - 1);
  }
);

stack(5);
```

Now for some reason I currently don't understand OpenSCAD tells me that I've got a syntax error in line 4, marking the editor like this:

[image: highlighted syntax error in the mentioned code]

Sadly the console only yields this output:

> ERROR: Parser error in line 4: syntax error
>
> ERROR: Compilation failed!

So it's somewhat hard for me to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.
I guess there's a way to do this using `for`, but I would consider a recursive approach more readable.

I'll try to do this with modules, and if that doesn't work I can resort to use `for` in combination with modules I suppose - it's more that I'd like this to work and find it very readable.

---

Update: So from the [OpenSCAD User Manual](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language) I get this snippet:
[image: OpenSCAD definition of modules and functions]

I would tend to interpret this so that it is not possible to create a recursive structure the way I imagined.

Instead I could:

- Use a helper function to generate the cube parameters and compute their union afterwards.
- Rewrite the structure in terms of a `for` loop.

I'm uncertain whether my conviction is correct, but the reasoning is this:

1. I cannot create objects in a function because that would have an effect.
2. I cannot use a module recursively because it doesn't return a result and possibly the way variables work in OpenSCAD would interfere with the idea.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#Recursive_Modules

Comment: Ah, thanks for the pointer! That one works indeed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a recursive module, the only problem there is the ternary operator takes values not objects:

```
module stack(levels) {
  if(levels) {
    cube([1,1,1], center=true);
    translate([0, 0, 0.9]) scale([1, 1, 0.9]) stack(levels-1);      
  } else {
    cube([1,1,1], center=true);
  }
}

stack(5);
```

Here's another example: https://github.com/cashlo/OpenSCAN-Objects/blob/master/xmas-tree.scad